# Javascript get element index position in DOM array by class or id

Tags: javascript, dom, selector, element

My situation

```
var domElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Now I want to return the array item key - position of the element in the array - ( for example `domElements[34]`) searching in the array for the element with `id="asd"`.

How can I achieve this?

What if instead of ID I want to search trough `class="asd hey"` ?

Any help appreciated, thank you!

NB: Not in jquery, I need it in pure javascript in this case

Comment: @fuyushimoya nope, updated question, i need pure js sorry :P

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kb3621gb/1/ see this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("#asd");
```

If you want to search by class

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll(".asd");
```

If you want an index of your code

try like this

```
var domElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

for(var i=0;i<domElements.length;i++){
   if(domElements[i].id==="asd"){
      // search by id 
      // index i 
   }
   if(domElements[i].className==="asd"){
      // search by class 
      // index i 
   }
}
```

**Edit**

There another way you can find index

try like this

```
var domElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
var domList= Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'));
var itemList = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".asd"));
console.log(domList.indexOf(itemList[0])) // if you wanna find one index

//if you wanna search all index of class 

for(var i=0;i<itemList.length;i++)
  console.log(domList.indexOf(itemList[i]))
```

Comment: Sorry but i need to return the position in the domElements array, i can't do it straightfowardly

Comment: position means ?? index ??

Comment: Thank you, i will wait a little to see if any better solution, otherwise i'll accept your, thanks!!

Comment: @sbaaaang i have added another way. Please try that :)

Answer (score 1):

Not literal code but if you iterate over the dom elements

```
for (var i = 0; i < parentElement.children.length; i++) {
    var item = parentElement.children[i];
    if (item.getAttribute('id') === 'asd') {
        return i;
    }
}
```

This has the assumption that instead of selecting ALL DOM elements, you simply select the `parentElement` of your list of elements - this approach is more logical and certainly a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking this:

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
function cutlistitem(lielm) {
lielm.addEventListener("click", function () {
    lielm.classList.toggle("done")
})
};
li.forEach(cutlistitem);
```

I was creating a todo list app in which I created an unordered list of tasks to be done, in that `<ul>` every task was in an `<li>`.
Now what I wanted is: to add an event listener to every `li` element for which I needed to grab every element of `li` list. I ran a `forEach` loop on every element of `li` list and added an event listener to each of the element. To get and index of the element you can use `indexOf` method.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to do it

```
var list = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.class-name'));
var listIndex = list.filter(function(el, index){
    if(el.id === 'id'){
       return index;
    }
})
```